# Angular2 update image [src] after server upload

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app.
It has a component that allows a user to crop and upload an image to the server.
The parent component shows the image in a src tag.
I need to be able to update this src tag once an updated image is uploaded.
The link in the src tag will always be the same.
Once I manually refresh the browser I see the newly uploaded image.

Here is my image in the HTML. The URL is defined in the component...

```
<img  [src]="url" />
```

The parent component hosts the image upload component like so...

```
<imageUploadCropper [postUrl]="postimageProfileUrl"></imageUploadCropper>
```

The image upload component will upload an image like so...

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("uploadedImage", this.data.image);

    this._http.post(this.postUrl, formData, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe();
```

How do I reload an image in Angular2?
Should I just reload the page/route or this there another way? Would using Zones help somehow?

Comment: Its not an Angular problem. Its a cache problem. Change your url format to allow versioning or add a `?` add the end of your url following by your file version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to change `src` to reload. One of the solutions can be adding random string to the end of the url.

```
this._http.post(this.postUrl, formData, { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(() => this.url += '?random+\=' + Math.random());
```

Comment: I thought about using a cache breaker like this but was hoping there was a cleaner ng2 way. So is there no way we can refresh the image element without adding to the url?

Comment: The cache bust has nothing to do with Angular 2, that's just a "web thing".
An alternative could be that you fetch the image itself, base64 encode it and update the source with the base64 data ...

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. It was what I suspected. I will have a play with it and see what I can come up with.